# Detecting small squares attached to something else on the image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I want to detect small squares circled in red on the image. But the problem is that they are on another white line. I want to know how to separate those squares from the white line and detect them.

[image: Squares to be detected encircled in red]

I have used OpenCV Python to write the code. What I have done until now is that I cropped the image so that I get access only to the circular part of the image. Then I cropped the image to get the required part that is the white line. Then I used erosion so that the white line will vanish and the squares remain in the image. Then used Hough circles to detect the squares. This does work for some images but it cannot be generalized. Please help me in finding a generalized code for this. Let me know the logic and also the python code.
[image: Cropped image with the arena(ring)]

[image: Cropped image with the white line]

[image: Eroded image with remains of those 8 squares after erosion]

[image: Final image with detected squares]

Also could anyone help me detect that aruco marker on the image. Its getting rejected. I dont know why.
Image is in this link. [Detect small squares on an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59954111/detect-small-squares-on-an-image)

Comment: you could try distanceTransform on the b/w image and find local maxima there.

Comment: I am new to OpenCV. Could you tell me a bit about distance transform? Like what it actually does.

Comment: for all non-black pixels: computing the distance to the closest black pixel.

Comment: Why Hough? After the erosion you have already detected the squares. Why is that detection not good enough?

Comment: This is not a feasible solution because there will be a bot placed on the white line which will make detecting the white circle harder. So is there any way I could separate squares from the white line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's C++ code with distanceTransform.
Since I nearly only used openCV functions, you can probably easily convert it to Python code.

I removed the white stripe at the top of the image manually, hope this isn't a problem.

```
int main()
{
    cv::Mat input =  cv::imread("C:/StackOverflow/Input/SQUARES.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    cv::Mat thres = input > 0; // make binary mas
    cv::Mat dst;
    cv::distanceTransform(thres, dst, CV_DIST_L2, 3);

    double min, max;
    cv::Point minPt, maxPt;
    cv::minMaxLoc(dst, &min, &max, 0, 0);

    double distThres = max*0.65; // a real clustering would be better. This assumes that the white circle thickness is a bout 50% of the square size, so 65% should be ok...

    cv::Mat squaresMask = dst >= distThres;

    cv::imwrite("C:/StackOverflow/Input/SQUARES_mask.png", squaresMask);

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    cv::findContours(squaresMask, contours, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);


    cv::Mat output;
    cv::cvtColor(input, output, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
    {
        cv::Point2f center;
        float radius;
        cv::minEnclosingCircle(contours[i], center, radius);

        cv::circle(output, center, 5, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 255), -1);
        //cv::circle(output, center, radius, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 255), 1);
    }

    cv::imwrite("C:/StackOverflow/Input/SQUARES_output.png", output);

    cv::imshow("output", output);
    cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

this is the input:

[image]

this it the squaresMask after distance transform

[image]

and this is the result

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Is there any other way that you could solve this problem by separating the squares from the white line? Because I got to know that there will be a bot placed on the white circle!!

Comment: sorry, I don't understand. Can you show an image with such a bot? You could maybe just detect where the white circle is interrupted.

Comment: Refer the question asked on this site. I have provided with an image there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59954111/detect-small-squares-on-an-image

Comment: maybe you could try to detect the bot with a different method independently from finding the squares

Comment: How does that help in detecting squares?

Comment: the robot shouldnt be a problem for detecting the white squares with my algorithm

Comment: Ok, Thank you. Could you also help me in detecting that Aruco on the bot and provide the code for the same. The image is in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59954111/detect-small-squares-on-an-image

Comment: sorry, I dont have experience with aruco marker detection.